# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a vba macro to get data from sheets of an excel document, way that I do it:

```
Worksheets("EN").Range("5A").value
```

But for some reason Run Time Error 1004 is outputted. If I try to loop Worksheets elements and see the Name or Index value, all sheets are properly get, but when I try to get .Range("5A").value 1004 Error is outputted.
For some reason, value command is with minus "v", if I try to put Value key, IDE automatically change the key "Value" to "value".

what can explain this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Worksheets("EN").Range("A5").value

Answer (score 1):

It's Range("a5") not range("5a")
Column letter then row number